# UPDATE TABLE SQL Missing expression error

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
UPDATE factorial
    SET factorial.SQUARE = factorial.num**2, factorial.ROOT = SQRT(factorial.num);
```

Error:

> 936. 00000 -  "missing expression"

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are using.

Comment: Well you misspelled `factoial`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the table prefixes and the extra *.

```
UPDATE factorial SET SQUARE = num*2, ROOT = SQRT(num);
```

Careful with updates without a where clause, as they will update all the records from your table.